# Reading from text file line by line in Java

Tags: java

How I can read the content from a text file line by line? When I try to output the content, the newline character seems to be ignored from reading.

```
public class ReadFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str= "";

        //Reading content from file
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("text.txt"));
        while(in.hasNextLine()){
            str = str + in.nextLine();
            str.concat("\n");      //Not working!!!!!!!!!!!
        }

        in.close();

        //Writing content to another file
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
        out.println(str);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `Scanner.nextLine` will strip the linebreak. `PrintWriter.println` will add it back. Where's the problem?

Comment: `String` is **immutable**. `String.concat` is conventionally written as `+` - it's both shorter and more readable. `str += "\n"`. "\n" is a UNIX linebreak - this won't work on Windows.

Comment: Are you on windows ? you should try appending `\r\n` instead of only `\n`.

Comment: @11thdimension OP is not appending anything.

Comment: `str.concat("\n");` I meant this line, he is probably opening the file in windows specific editor and not able to see the line separations.

Comment: @11thdimension no. This line is a noop. It creates a new String with `\n` at the end, but doesn't do anything with that new String. It should be `str = str.concat("\n");`, or simply `str += '\n';`

Comment: Instead of loading the whole file in memory in a huge string, using STring concatenation at each step which is slower and slower due to the copies of the bigger and bigger strings that need to be made, why don't you simply println() each read line to the PrintWriter: less memory, much faster, and simpler.

Comment: @JBNizet, yes you're right. I missed that.

Comment: The cases where you have to read an entire file into memory before you can process any of it are very few and far between, and this is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

You are making mistake in the following line:

```
str.concat("\n");
```

Update it like below:

```
str = str.concat("\n");
```

I am giving updated program.

```
public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
                Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("text.txt"));) {
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                out.println(in.nextLine());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the string to the new value after your concat operation.

```
str = str.concat("\n"); // or \r\n for Windows.
```

Answer (score -2):

You are concatenating string which is not very efficient; use StringBuilder, also use platform independent line terminator.

Try this instead :

```
public class ReadFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String str= "";

        //Reading content from file
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("text.txt"));
        StringBuilder str  = new StringBuilder();
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while(in.hasNextLine()){            
            str.append(in.nextLine()).append(newLine);
        }

        in.close();

        //Writing content to another file
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("output.txt"));
        out.println(str.toString());
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: You advise to use a platform-independent line terminator, but your code doesn't. It also doesn't compile.

Comment: Still doesn't compile.

Comment: And you haven't identified the actual problem.